# Accept credit card payments without account

Tags: paypal

I have Premiere account that is verified and I can accept PayPal payments.
But when I create donate or buy now button and click on it I see that non users have to create their PayPal account to pay me. How to enable them to pay to me without they having account?

I guess there is some option for that but I can't find it. Does anyone use it?

Comment: Can someone explain to me, why this is programming related. This is clearly off topic.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to make sure that you have PayPal account optional turned on in your account.  You can turn this on by logging into your account and going into your profile settings.  Then go to my selling tools and then into website payment perferences.  The option to turn PayPal account on should be at the bottom of the page.

Comment: I have only these options:Auto Return for Website Payments, Payment Data Transfer (optional), Encrypted Website Payments, Contact Telephone Number, Express Checkout Settings.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of what you are seeing.  Can you provide your merchant id as well, and I will take a look at the account on my end.

Comment: I think it is because of my country

Comment: That could be, not all countries have this feature available.  What country is your account set up under?

Answer (score 0):

When user will pay via credit card, he have to have a PayPal account?
I want that my users can pay product with credit card via paypal form.

Answer (score 0):

This answers yoru question:

https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/mer/WAX_landing-outside

Premier and Business account holders may optionally set that their customers are NOT required to sign in with their PayPal account.